# What is an equivalent of LoggerRepository in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I want to migrate from  Log4j 1.x to log4j2 so I read this article:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

In our application we are using LoggerRepository:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().getLoggerRepository().getCurrentLoggers();
```

what is the equivalent of this piece of code in log4j2. Because in article they said we can't access to this method but they don't mention how should I replace it

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your need correctly, you can go via [`LogManager`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.html#getConfiguration()) to get the [`LoggerContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.html#getConfiguration())'s configuration and retrieve the `Logger`s from that:

```
LoggerContext ctx = LogManager.getContext();
Configuration cfg = ctx.getConfiguration();
Map<String, LoggerConfig> loggers = cfg.getLoggers();
```